# How to get value greater than multiple columns value rather than using composite key field from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

If I have table that contains following data :

branch, type, number  => this will generate composite key string 'keyfield'

the length of branch, type is [int] [4]
the length of number is [int] [7]

Data is like this:

```
branch, type, number
13,     1309,   1    row1
13,     1309,   2    row2
13,     1310,   1    row3
14,     1309,   1    row4
```

so I have keyfield -> called 'KeyField' column but idont need to use it, it works but i need to just use expression rather than string keyfield
for example :
if I need to get the row greater than row2 above:
I wrote:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE WHERE KeyField > '0013130900002'
```

--> I don't like to using string for composite key ..

Also I cannot make it manually like this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM  TABLE WHERE brn > 1 AND type > 1309 and num > 2
```

it will not work... so I need to just get next row by expression

for example : getGreatRow(1, 1309, 2) ; // this will return row3 that what I need to do.
so that this function can used with C# directly and textboxes on screens !!
I need to select the only top 1 record greater than value of current record or expression I specified .

**Edit**

I used Gordon SQL to generate a C# with list of primary keys as I wanted. Thanks to Gordon.

In C# to make SQL query auto generated:

```
public List<EntryTable> Tables { get; private set; }
public List<BufferElement> Buffer { get; private set; }
 string Query = string.Empty;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Tables[0].PrimaryKeys.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Query += "(";
                        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                        {
                            switch (Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].CLRType)
                            {
                                case CLRType.CLR_BYTE:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = {Convert.ToByte(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)} AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_INT16:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = {Convert.ToInt16(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)} AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_INT32:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = {Convert.ToInt32(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)} AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_INT64:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = {Convert.ToInt64(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)} AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_SINGLE:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = {Convert.ToSingle(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)} AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_DOUBLE:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = {Convert.ToDouble(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)} AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_DECIMAL:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = {Convert.ToDecimal(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)} AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_Boolean:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = {Convert.ToBoolean(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)} AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_STRING:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = '{Convert.ToString(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)}' AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_DATETIME:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = '{Convert.ToDateTime(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)}' AND ";
                                    break;
                                case CLRType.CLR_TIME:
                                    Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart} = '{TimeSpan.Parse(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[j].KeyPart).Value)}' AND ";
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        switch (Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].CLRType)
                        {
                            case CLRType.CLR_BYTE:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > {Convert.ToByte(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_INT16:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > {Convert.ToInt16(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_INT32:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > {Convert.ToInt32(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_INT64:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > {Convert.ToInt64(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_SINGLE:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > {Convert.ToSingle(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_DOUBLE:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > {Convert.ToDouble(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_DECIMAL:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > {Convert.ToDecimal(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_Boolean:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > {Convert.ToBoolean(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_STRING:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > '{Convert.ToString(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}'";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_DATETIME:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > '{Convert.ToDateTime(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}'";
                                break;
                            case CLRType.CLR_TIME:
                                Query += $"{Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart} > '{TimeSpan.Parse(Buffer.Find(x => x.ID == Tables[0].PrimaryKeys[i].KeyPart).Value)}'";
                                break;
                        }
                        Query += $") {(Tables[0].PrimaryKeys.Count > 1 && i != Tables[0].PrimaryKeys.Count - 1 ? " OR " : string.Empty)} \n";
                    }

                    Query += $"ORDER BY {string.Join(" ASC, ", Tables[0].PrimaryKeys.Select(x => x.KeyPart).ToArray())} ASC";

                    SelectCommand = $"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {Tables[0].Table} WHERE " + Query;
```

Comment: Are you using `mysql` or `sql-server`? Please don't add irrelevant tags. Also what relevance does this have to `C#`?

Comment: iam sorry :( its a c# entry screen that  i need to get greater expression of current record on textbox.

Comment: in your example, don't you mean  getGreatRow(13, 1309, 2)?      that is, branch 13 instead of 1.     
if you really meant getGreatRow(1, 1309, 2) then the function should return row 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the next row after `1, 1309, 2`

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TABLE
WHERE brn > 1 OR
      (brn = 1 AND type > 1309) OR
      (brn = 1 AND type = 1309 AND num > 2)
ORDER BY brn DESC, type DESC, num DESC;
```

Comment: does it should be like this ?? SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AccTransHed
WHERE thd_brn > 13 or
      (thd_brn = 13 AND thd_typ > 1309) OR
      (thd_brn = 13 AND thd_typ = 1309 AND thd_num > 149)

Comment: @Gordon is using the values you used in your example  "getGreatRow(1, 1309, 2)".   you probably meant  getGreatRow(13, 1309, 2),  but we can't read your mind.  :-)

Comment: Gordon, Kamal (indirectly) notes that the last line in your where clause should say  "...type = 1309..." instead of "...type > 1309..." ?    I can't edit it because it's only a one-character change.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you tu use 'math': put your column in a 'relevant order then multiply to accomodate all the figures in a single field. ex:
`new_id=first_column*100000+second_column*10+third_column`

so in case of row 1 you'll have 1313091 as code. Math is by-far faster than string manipulation. You then will able to query dividing the key by what part you need. eventually adding some more zeros to columns you think will grow much.

The ordering is kept as you build the key with columns in order you need  outer.

so your query will be like:

```
select *
from table
where new_id > (branch)*100000+(type)*10+number
```

the IDEA is this:

```
123456 99349199 12341234 : having enough space for a 'reasonable' amount of numbers
000000 00000000 00000000

so 123456 x 1 00000000 00000000  = 123456 00000000 00000000  +

   99349199 x 1 00000000         =        99349199 00000000  +
and
   12341234 x                      1 =            12341234  =                  
                                  -------------------------
                                  123456 99349199 12341234
```

UPDATED:

```
select *
from my_table
WHERE new_id (branch)*1 00000000 00000000+(type)*1 00000000+number
```

obviusly our 'new_label' definition changed:

```
new_label= (branch)*100000000 00000000+(type)*100000000 + number
```

so you can have these maximum lenghts:

```
<all digits you want> (branch) + 8 digit (type) + 8 digit (number)
```

I suggest you to add your database triggers to enforce these maximum lenghts

Comment: its not worked in this record number 153    Record = '131309153'  yes its very fast but i dont really understand anything about Math !! i just hard can adding two numbers lol so please explain how to fix it,         also what if there's fourth column that take string literal !    so that i need expression GetGreaterRow(field1, field2, field3, field4, fieldN)

Comment: What are the maximum lenghts of your columns? I assumed sizes to be (uninportant), 4 and 1 digit. If your fields are longer you need more '0s. eg: add some more 0s where needed. 00 000000 0 is the pattern I had, if your is XX XXXXXX XX you need to ad 'a zero' to each of your factors

Comment: Please sir explain this types of pattern because iam very weak at Math. all i need the dynamic size of columns can changed at design time of data entry screen for example the branch can be 4,  the type also 4 but the number for some users will be  9, or 7 depending of number of transactions that they can have

Comment: I suggest you to use a bin amount of 0s: 0000 0000000000 0000 so there's enough room

Comment: man the problem that i dont understand , what zeros should be for 4 length column ? and what should for 6 length column, please forgive me am from middle east.

Comment: Plerase print the `select max(branch), max(type) and max(number) from your_table` so I can give you a reasonable number of 0s

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mhwm78   but man there's maybe 1 milion invoices can be made !

Comment: picture is unreadable: please post code as text (you can tell sqlserver to output as text)

Comment: is there any simple way rather than math or implement function like GetNextKey(expressions) i wish :)

Comment: It depends on what you need it for

Comment: 14 1310 91225         brn ,typ ,num    but numbers can be 1 milion

Comment: In the little table above number up to 99 999 999 could be handled (100M). THIS: `(branch)*1 000000000000 00000000+(type)*100000000+number` could hold up to 100M unique numbers (for same branch and type). Also new_id has to be adapted with these new values

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mhwthl   this is picture i wish it works, if u explain how to make where clause to already single numbers,      WHERE should change every pointer moving.... i think that

Comment: thank you Sir, i wish to know also from you the second answer of guy below how it works also xD

Answer (score 0):

Create this function in your database

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCompositeKey(@branch int, @type int, @number int)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN cast(@branch as bigint) * 100000000000 + cast(@type as bigint) * 10000000 + @number
END
```

and then use it during your comparisons, like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TABLE]
WHERE dbo.GetCompositeKey(branch, type, number) > 
      dbo.GetCompositeKey(13, 1309, 2)        
ORDER BY dbo.GetCompositeKey(branch, type, number)
```

note: this query is simplified for illustration. When executing it from C#, you should use a parameterized query to provide the 3 integers to the SQL function, to avoid a SQL injection attack.

---

EDIT:  After posting this, I read in some comments on other answers where you say that you don't understand math.  In most of the answers so far, the approach was simply to create a large integer combining all 3 of your values (branch, type, and number) to create a comparable value. In fact, it's the same thing you did using string concatenation with the string-based composite key in your question ('0013130900002'). As pointed out in another answer, the mathematical approach should be faster. Another error in your string was zero-filling the @number field only to 5 digits, when you've already stated it must be able to hold a 7-digit number.

Respectfully, all the answers so far use very basic math.  You won't be able to get very far as a programmer if you don't understand basic math, so you should make it a priority to improve that skill.

Comment: Yes, but what if there's fourth column as string ?   so i need simple solution because  i really do simple thing.      getNextKeyOfExpression(col1, col2, col3, col4) thats all i was need :)

Comment: your question said you needed the ROW.  you're adding a new requirement now.

Comment: function assuming to wrorking for me,  but it takes 400ms 500ms to run,  the answer of Gordon take only 3 ms ??? HELL math xD   any fix for that beauty function to make more fast ? u have any suggest sir.

Comment: @Gordon's answer is more performant.  if you like the function approach, you could work Gordon's code into a function

Comment: the problem why i need to using this approach, for navigating through records ( very very big records ) 1 milion of transactions, without filling a Dataset and start implementing MoveNext, Previous, First, Last.... so that i was searching for simple way of moving to next record key when current expression is XXXX,   also expression may contain string field  ( 'M', 100, 200, 100)

Comment: also how to make function to work with previous record ? get previous key.  sorry for disturbing you. please srry :)

Comment: As I said above, you're adding new requirements. you said nothing in your question about a string field being one of the key fields.   and nothing about not wanting to fill a DataSet.   Those requirements change the suggested approach AFTER people have already answered your question.

Comment: To get the previous record, change the query to use  < instead of >,  and add  DESC (descending order) to the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You've said in comments on other answers that you don't want to fill a DataSet or use MoveNext, etc.   Another approach would be to create a view that includes a composite key.

First, create the function I defined in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54575863/1633949)

Then, create the view

```
CREATE VIEW [myview]
AS
SELECT 
    *,
    dbo.GetCompositeKey(branch, type, number) as CompositeKey
FROM [table]
```

Query it like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [myview] 
WHERE CompositeKey > dbo.GetCompositeKey(13, 1309, 2)        
ORDER BY CompositeKey
```

This approach *might* improve query performance over my other answer. You'll need to test it to find out.